# Can I stay on Kubuntu 16.04 LTS if I did a clean install of Kubuntu 16.04.2?

Tags: kernel, kubuntu

Because I did a clean install of Kubuntu 16.04.2, I now have this kernel: `4.8.0-58-generic`. I understand that support for this kernel is limited to six months and will [end in August 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=16.04.x+Ubuntu+Kernel+Support+Schedule.svg).

What do I do at that time? Will I automatically be upgraded to a newer kernel series when Kubuntu 16.04.3 is released while still staying with Kubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: "What do I do at that time?" Whatever you want. Kernel updates are a major part of security updates and failure to update your kernel places you at security risks, In addition if you have any problem with the kernel you will be asked first to run a current kernel before filing bug reports. So you will loose support and expose yourself to security risks and you will have to decide what to do with that information.

Comment: Either stay with an old kernel and accept the lack of support or upgrade. Why would you not upgrade ?

Comment: I'm sorry for not making myself clear: do I need to do something special to upgrade the kernel or will it be available when I run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? I have no objection to upgrading the kernel if I can stay with 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Generally speaking, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` is sufficient. dist-upgrade does not upgrade ubuntu to a new version, see the man page for details.

Comment: I do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get the kernel fixes as well. If `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is all that is needed when 16.04.3 comes along, I'll be all set.

Comment: Why are you so hung up on "dist-upgrade" ? Do you understand the difference between `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` ? They do the same thing with the exception that upgrade will not remove packages and dist-upgrade will. There are occasional times when dist-upgrade is necessary but they are rare. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt-get.8.html. This is completely different from upgrading to a new version of ubuntu - which is do-release-upgrade https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the limited kernel support.

Starting with 16.04 the HWE stacks are "rolling".

Your kernel will be upgraded to 4.10 when the 4.8 reaches End of Life.

Comment: Thank you! This link is for reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack